# script on a remote machine that archive files fails

Tags: ssh, shell, script, tar

I have a simple script (Given below) on a machine that collect files from several folders into a single one and then archive it. The script works as expected on the remote machine. When I run it via ssh (`ssh user@machine -f 'path.to.script'`) I get this output

tar: toSend: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
Killed by signal 1.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

archfile=~/fastspace/toSend.tgz
dir=~/fastspace/toSend
if [ -f $archfile ] ; then
    rm $archfile
fi

if [ -d $dir ]; then
    rm -r $dir
fi

mkdir $dir

for i in {1..20}; do
    cp ~/fastspace/prog/mn0.$i/resSum.dat $dir/res$i
    cp ~/fastspace/prog/mn0.$i/parOut.dat $dir/pars$i
done

tar cvfz $archfile toSend

rm -r $dir
```

Comment: Try `tar cvfz $archfile $dir` instead of `tar cvfz $archfile toSend`.

Comment: @ott In that case I get the complete folder tree of toSend instead of the folder itself. Apart from that, this is good.

Comment: Ah, then you want to chdir to the folder above. Then change it to `tar cvfz $archfile -C ~/fastspace toSend`.

Comment: Your command isn't accepted by bash. I'm also not sure I understood your suggestion. You suggest I'll log into the remote machine and run it from there? or add chdir line in which I'll go to the folder in which I wish yo place the folders?

Comment: You should change the tar command in your script. The `-C ~/fastspace` means `chdir to ~/faszspace` before starting to archive the toSend dir`.

Comment: Shouldn't it read then ``tar cvfz -C ~/fastspace $archfile toSend``? Also the script is placed at the same path as the toSend dir

Comment: If the script was at the same path, then it wouldn't output an error message. `tar cvfz` is a relict from earlier versions, maybe you specify all options with `-`, that is `tar -czvf $archfile -C ~/fastspace toSend`.

Comment: No. This doesn't work either. I think this might has something to do with the filesystem. The remote machine is a cluster manager and has an nfs file system.